# pyqt5 проблема с частотой обновления mouseMoveEvent

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Я решил создать совместную онлайн-рисовалку для меня и моих друзей. Для этого я собрался использовать pyqt5 и socket (ни ту , ни другую библиотеку я совершенно не знаю (знаком только с tkinter)). Рисование кистью я реализовал с помощью mouseMoveEvent и создания множества точек(код прикреплю ниже). На этом этапе я обнаружил проблему. При слишком быстром движении мышкой получаются разрывы. Я предположил два возможных варианта решения задачи : либо увеличить частоту обновления mouseMoveEvent , либо установить ограничение для максимальной скорости мыши. Я поискал похожие запросы , но нашёл лишь один(к сожалению ответ на него мне не помог). Я надеюсь на Вашу помощь в решении этого вопроса(я впервые на этом форуме , заранее прошу прощения если был слишком многословен).

```
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Brush_Editor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, value_now, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window)
        self.vn = value_now
        self.slader()

    def slader(self):
        self.sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.sld.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.sld.setGeometry(30, 40, 240, 45)
        self.sld.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValue)
        self.sld.show()
        self.sld.setValue(self.vn)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('BrushEditor')
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.show()

    def changeValue(self, value):
        global brush_size
        brush_size = value + 1


class Colour_Editor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window)
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('ColourEditor')
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        ##  Buttons
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Yellow", self)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Black", self)
        self.button3 = QPushButton("Blue", self)
        self.button4 = QPushButton("Green", self)
        self.button1.move(30, 10)
        self.button2.move(30, 60)
        self.button3.move(30, 110)
        self.button4.move(30, 160)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_colour(Qt.yellow))
        self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_colour(Qt.black))
        self.button3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_colour(Qt.blue))
        self.button4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.change_colour(Qt.green))
        self.show()

    def change_colour(self, colour):
        global main_colour
        main_colour = colour


class Main_Window(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        global main_colour
        super(Main_Window, self).__init__()
        self.brush_size = 4
        self.standart = True
        self.__zoom = 0
        main_colour = Qt.black
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setWindowTitle('OnlinePaint')
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.move(0, 0)
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Colours", self)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Brush", self)
        self.button3 = QPushButton("Clear", self)
        self.button2.move(70, 0)
        self.button3.move(140, 0)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.colour_editor())
        self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.brush_editor())
        self.button3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clear())

    def colour_editor(self):
        self.ce = Colour_Editor(self)
        self.ce.move(0, 70)
        self.ce.show()

    def brush_editor(self):
        self.standart = False
        self.br = Brush_Editor(self.brush_size, self)
        self.br.move(0, 470)
        self.br.show()

    def clear(self):
        self.scene.clear()
        print("clear")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.drawing(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())
        super(Main_Window, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.drawing(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())
        super(Main_Window, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            factor = 1.25
            self.__zoom += 1
        else:
            factor = 0.8
            self.__zoom -= 1
        self.scale(factor, factor)

    def drawing(self, x, y):
        if self.standart:
            self.brush_size = 4
        else:
            self.brush_size = brush_size
        self.scene.addEllipse(x, y, self.brush_size, self.brush_size, QPen(main_colour), QBrush(main_colour))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    MW = Main_Window()
    MW.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: На питоне gui для онлайна не сделать, только бэкэнд.

Comment: Скажите , пожалуйста, что это подразумевает (я не разбираюсь от слова совсем). Я посмотрел пару видео о сокете и примерно понял его работу. Я хочу сохранять сцену после каждого действия игрока , потом отправлять это на сервер , а потом другим игрокам.

Comment: А, в этом смысле онлайн, ну тогда да, подойдет. А по-сути вопроса рекомендую читать документацию по теме QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem  и так далее. Тема довольно обширная, чтобы в двух словах рассказать

Comment: Хорошо , спасибо Вам большое за совет! Я посмотрю , но пока оставлю вопрос открытым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос исчерпан, я неправильно начал проект. Я буду его переписывать, но уже на другой библиотеке.